# Problem with GTK+ themes on Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: 14.04, themes, gtk, ubuntu-gnome

**Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 LTS**

When I choose any GTK+ theme in GNOME Tweak this problem of broken interface occurs:

[image]

[image]

I tried the folowing themes: Ultimate Blue, Sierra, Matcha. Each has the same problem.

Terminal output of `apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0` command:

```
libgtk2.0-0:
  Instalado: 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2
  Candidato: 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.24.30-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libgtk-3-0:
  Instalado: 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3
  Candidato: 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.18.9-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply an issue of incompatibility. Both [Matcha](https://github.com/vinceliuice/matcha) and [Sierra](https://github.com/vinceliuice/Sierra-gtk-theme) require GTK+ 3.20 or later, whereas in your system you have GTK+ 3.18 (3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 to be precise as per the info you provided). Hence those themes don't work properly in your system.

So either you'll have to install and use a GTK+ theme which supports version 3.18 or you may request the developers of these themes to provide support for GTK+ 3.18 and hope that they'll grant your request.

You may also consider updating to a newer release. Both Ubuntu 17.10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (to be officially released in a week or so) have GTK+ 3.22.

<sub>I couldn't find any info about the "*Ultimate Blue*" theme you mentioned, but I presume something similar happens with it.</sub>